# (Re)move the 10 rep hurdle for creating wiki posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, community-wiki

Is there any reason to prohibit users less than 10 rep from ticking the wiki check mark?

I see no real abuse vector by allowing this immediately. I do see a downside in granting a user a perk that doesn't help them use the site as a new user. The distinction between normal post and wiki post in no way helps a new user focus on what they need to learn with only 10 reputation.

The only benefit I see is to simplify UI clutter and choice for new users, but if that's the intent, 10 rep it too low to expect someone to know how and when to deploy a CW post. (And too soon to start cluttering the UI) If so, I'd suggest raising the bar to 100 for a combined create and edit of wikis perk. That would keep an esoteric option off the table early and teach users why to wiki he same time they can edit a wiki post without supervision.

Comment: So you want to either lower the rep requirement to zero, or raise it to 100?

Comment: Yes - I feel having it at 10 is worse than the two options I presented. Unless I'm wrong about the need to have anyone locked out of the option I say get rid of the code and simplify the privilege chart. Less rungs on the ladder make the remaining ones more meaningful. Less code makes the site better.

Comment: The 10 rep requirement is probably there to prevent new folks from accidentally ticking the checkbox.  It seems to work.  Unintentional CW questions happened often enough to be a bother.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it happened often enough to cause the team to disable it altogether, letting ordinary users wikify only their answers. Only a mod can mark a question as CW.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there's a *huge* benefit to this hurdle: without it, folks click that checkbox accidentally (or out of curiosity, or because they like clicking things... whatever, they click it) and then don't get reputation for their answers and don't know why.

[image: Wait until they have the motor skills to aim, dammit!]

They can't *uncheck it* after the post is live. They have to get a moderator to do it. And they don't know to do that either.

It caused way more confusion than it ever helped; not a lot of brand-new users need to create wikis.

Comment: User with 1 rep also can't flag so if he marked his first and only answer as CW he's doomed.

Comment: Do you know what percentage of these new users can wash themselves? They don't seem very clever.

Comment: Do you feel 10 is the exact right spot for this checkmark to be introduced to users? My feeling is the site would be better if it were moved and clearly it can't go lower for good reasons I didn't consider / realize.

Comment: The exact right spot is probably 17, @bmike. But there's nothing else at 17, and it's kind of a sad little privilege to put there on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I like having that restriction there because it increases the odds users have asked one successful question before posting a wiki question.

Giving that option to new users could give them one more excuse for posting unnecessary questions that either aren't appropriate for the site or aren't thought through. For example someone might think "Oh, it's ok that I haven't tried anything yet, I'll just make this a wiki"

Comment: It's unlikely that a new user even knows what a Wiki question is.  I'm pretty sure that CW is an SE-specific concept.

Comment: Which is why the confusion might lead to the line of thought I presented.

Comment: User can mark only answer as CW, not a question.